# How do I detect the group used by docker daemon?

Tags: docker

Based on version and distribution, Docker service can run using different groups (as `root`, `docker`, `dockerroot`)

I am looking for a portable way to retrieve the group name used by it, so I can add an user to that group.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not yet convinced that this is the best approach this worked:

```
ps -f -o rgid= --no-headers $(pgrep dockerd)
```

I mention that this retrieves the group id, which is maybe better as some groups may not have a name.

Answer (score 0):

```
stat -c '%G' /var/run/docker.sock
```